# There are 7 people (two of which are John and Andy) in a group. The group must consist of 4, 5, or 6 people.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

There are 7 people (two of which are John and Andy) in a group. The group must consist of 4, 5, or 6 people. Find the probability that John is in the group if the probability for each group size is the same.

So I have found the probability for each group size, for 4-people it is 4/7, for 5-people it is 5/7 and for 6 people it is 6/7.

My question is, do I multiply the probabilities here, or what should my next step be?

Comment: "There are 7 people in a group. The group must consist of 4, 5 or 6 people." seems contradictory. Do you mean that we have 7 people to choose from to make a group?

Comment: What does the question have to do with Andy?

Comment: @Arthur sorry yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @MathLover Andy would be irrelevant in this question.

Comment: In any case you should add them after multiplying each by 1/3

Comment: The probability of each of the three group sizes is $1/3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "the probability for each group size is the same" so, since there are three possible group sizes, this may be $\frac13$ for each size

That makes the overall probability $$\frac13 \times \frac47 + \frac13 \times \frac57 + \frac13 \times \frac67 =\frac57$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the probability for each of the group sizes is equal, we can take the average of the probabilities 4/7, 5/7, and 6/7 to get a probability of 5/7.